# Почему не получается распарсить строку заданным регулярным выражением

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Мне необходимо достать из строки префикс, имя и сообщение игрока.
Обычно сообщение выглядит так:

> ? ???  [Префикс] Имя  ? Сообщение

Иногда первый `?` убирается.

Я составил такое регулярное выражение:

```
.{0,}(\[.{0,}\])\1{0,} (.{0,})\?(.{0,})
```

И вот такой код использую:

```
System.out.println("[NChatBot] Processing chat line: " + msg);
Matcher _m = _namePattern.matcher(msg);
boolean found = false;
while (_m.find()) {
    found = true;
    System.out.println("1: " + _m.group(1));
    System.out.println("2: " + _m.group(2));
    System.out.println("3: " + _m.group(3));
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Can't parse!");
}
```

Но каждый раз получаю на выходе:

> [STDOUT]: [NChatBot] Processing chat line: ???  [Player] Playername  ? msg
>   [STDOUT]: Can't parse!

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте `Pattern _namePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\[[^\\]\\[]*])\\s+(.*?)\\s*\\?\\s*(.*)")`

Comment: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html тут можно поэксперементировать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Следующий код](https://ideone.com/0fEX8x) находит необходимые значения:

```
String msg = "? ??? [Префикс] Имя ? Сообщение";
Pattern _namePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\[[^\\]\\[]*])\\s+(.*?)\\s*\\?\\s*(.*)");
Matcher _m = _namePattern.matcher(msg);
boolean found = false;
while(_m.find()) {
    found = true;
    System.out.println("1: "+_m.group(1));
    System.out.println("2: "+_m.group(2));
    System.out.println("3: "+_m.group(3));
}
if(!found) {
    System.out.println("Can't parse!");
}
```

**Подробности**:

- `(\\[[^\\]\\[]*])` - (группа №1) подстрока типа `[...]`
- `\\s+` - 1 и более  пробельных сиволов
- `(.*?)` - (группа №2) 0 и более любых символов, наименьшее кол-во до первого...
- `\\s*\\?\\s*` - знак `?` внутри 1 и более пробельных сиволов
- `(.*)` - (группа №3)  оставшаяся часть строки до конца.